# Mysql - Insert string with white space

Tags: mysql

How do I insert string with white spaces in VARCHAR?

```
insert into users (user_id,firstname,lastname,email,group) values('admin','some','Body','admin@something.com','Site admin');
```

This is giving me syntax error, I am new to mysql, I went through mysql documentation that doesnt give me clear idea why this behavior is.

```
 mysql> insert into users (user_id,firstname,lastname,email,group) values('admin','some','Body','admin@something.com','Site admin');
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group) values('admin','some','Body','admin@something.com','Site admin')' at line 1
```

Comment: Please paste the exact error you are getting.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the `insert` statement as you've given us.  Either you're getting an error because you're not properly connected to the database (or field types are wrong, etc.), or you're not showing us the real SQL statement.

Comment: Is userid a string or int? Also you should be able to have spaces in varchar.

Comment: @Amber -Updated my question with more details.

Comment: @mellamokb - question updated with more details.

Comment: @Gohn67 - question updated with more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`group` is a keyword in MySQL. Modify your query like this:

```
INSERT INTO users (user_id, firstname, lastname, email, `group`)
VALUES('admin', 'some', 'Body', 'admin@something.com', 'Site admin');
```

Answer (score 4):

Group is a keyword, you need to use back ticks like this `group` to make it so the group will be read as a table column instead

```
INSERT into users (user_id,firstname,lastname,email,`group`)
VALUES ('admin','some','Body','admin@something.com','Site admin');
```